# How to read the HP website? (existence of printer drivers)

Tags: hp-laserjet

As first - sorry if this is not a typical "superuser" question, but honestly I have no idea where I could otherwise post this (suggestions for alternatives are gladly accepted).

OK, I have to provide support, and find a driver for an HP printer (LaserJet 6L) for Windows XP..

And so I put in "`HP laserjet 6L driver`" in a search engine, and get this as first result:

[HP LaserJet 6L Printer series -  Download drivers and software - HP Business Support Center](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?pnameOID=14974&locale=en_US&taskId=135&prodSeriesId=25476&prodTypeId=18972). The page says:

> Choose your software/driver language:
>   ...
>    Select operating system
>   ...
>     Microsoft Windows XP

Fine, so I click on [Microsoft Windows XP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=14974&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=25476&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=228) and now I get:

> Subscribe to driver and support alerts
>   ...
>   Useful links
>    » Automatically check if your drivers need updating (MS Windows only)
>    » Selecting the Correct Printer Driver
>    » These downloads are available for customers according to the terms in the HP Software License Agreement. Certain software may require a valid warranty, current support contract with HP, or a license fee.
>   ...
>   Operating System: Microsoft Windows XP
>   By downloading, you agree to the terms and conditions of the HP Software License Agreement.
>   Choose your software/driver language:   Submit
>   Quick jump to downloads by category...
>    »    Application
>    »    Software

And then these are the links for "Application" and "Software":

> Application
>   Description
>      Shop for HP Supplies
>   Software
>   Description
>      Microsoft (R) Windows XP Compatibility Information

... which is to say, no driver :(

And finally, a particularly cynical comment at end:

> Did not find what you're looking for?
>     If what you were looking for is not listed, then it is not available for downloading from the web in this OS and language.

No, as a matter of fact, I did *not* find what I was looking for :/ The question is - *why*?

Is it that they do not want to support that particular printer for XP anymore? Does anyone know what the policy of HP on this is?

Heck, I think it would be so much more honest, that instead of all that legalese, they write something like: "*FU you poorass, we don't care about wasting our time on your crappy old OS and old printer; either buy new or don't nag us with support*" if that's what they mean; at least I'd know what to do (which is, not waste my time on the HP website).

Well, hope someone can clarify what is the intent of HP behind such a website organization..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some extended Googling brought me to [this](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=bpl11038). I am assuming you do not have the Pro.

> XP solution - HP also worked closely with Microsoft to add functionality to the in-box XP drivers, based on the unidriver and PostScript driver architectures. Updates to these drivers, providing additional functionality, are available through the Windows Update feature of Windows XP. Although HP worked to provide comparable functionality with the Windows XP drivers, some features may not be available via the in-box driver.

In short, you can't download a driver since there isn't one. The standard XP drivers via Windows Update is all you need.

Comment: Fantastic @Diago - many thanks for that answer! I wonder, why don't they put such info on the website? I certainly wouldn't have had to even write the post above if I knew that... Thanks again - Cheers!

Comment: PS: @Diago: what is this "`the Pro`" that you mentioned?

Comment: @sdaau In the document I link the refer to the 6L Pro which is a different printer.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification @Diago - I am not the owner of the printer, I was just trying to help out a friend... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I too have this printer. as far as I know, they stopped supporting it some time ago.
This may help.
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodSeriesId=25476&prodTypeId=18972&objectID=c00751649#A2